# Handling elements which returns String value in two lines

Tags: mobile, automation, appium, appium-ios, perfecto

I'm new to perfecto mobile device automation. I came across a name field which returns value in two lines in the application. Like below

```
School Name : ABCD
              INTERNATIONAL
```

I found the locator which is Xpath as //*[text()="ABCD INTERNATIONAL"], this returns value in two lines which I confirmed when I ran the code and asserted the value. So basically the error is like below

```
expected [ABCD INTERNATIONAL] but found [ABCD
INTERNATIONAL]
```

My feature file is like

```
Feature: Verify the school Details
Scenario : Verify the school Name
Given User logs into Application
When User verifies the school name as "ABCD INTERNATIONAL"
Then user logs of
```

Step Defenition:

```
@When("User verifies the school name as {string}")
    public void a_User_verifies_the_school_name_as (String Name) throws Exception {
         String School_Name = utility.getText(appiumDriver, "//*[text()="ABCD INTERNATIONAL"]);
           Assert.assertEquals(School_Name, Name);
    }
```

Your help in sorting out this will mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify your actual and expected string by using replaceAll() method.

Like replaceAll("\n",""); and replaceAll(" ",""). then compare both in assertion.
If it is not working then you have to use pattern matching by regular expression.